# SignalR Hubs: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'multipleFileHub' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I keep getting this error in my JavaScript no matter what fix I try.  It's almost as if $.connection is not being recognized even though I have all the SignalR JavaScript libraries in place in my _layout.  I get the following error in the Chrome browser console:Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot read property 'multipleFileHub' of undefined Index:508
(anonymous function) Index:508
x.event.dispatch jquery-2.0.2.js:4692
y.handle jquery-2.0.2.js:4376"  of undefined".

Does it matter that my Global.asax inherits from "StsMvcHttpApplication" rather than the standard "System.Web.HttpApplication"? And in my case, I have to put the "RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();" in my "RegisterRoutes" method rather than "Application_Start" since Application_Start doesn't fire fast enough... it starts hunting for controllers if I put it in the app start.

Would appreciate the help!  I'll show the layout code first and then all the separate pieces of code:

_LAYOUT

```
@section head
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Libs/jquery.validate.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Libs/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Libs/modernizr-2.6.2.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Libs/modernizr.custom.blobconstructor.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/SidebarMenu.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/BC_Common.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/scene.layoutservice.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/scene.dataservice.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/signalr/hubs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/scene.startup.js")
}
```

INDEX.CSHTML

```
        $('#dBtn').click(function () {
        var docIds = sceneLayoutService.getSelection();
        if (docIds.length === 0) {
            alert("you need to select one");
            return false;
        } else {
            var docIdsParam = jQuery.param(docIds.map(function (value) {
                return { "name": "docIds", "value": value };
            }));
            // Proxy created on the fly
            var test_connection = $.connection.multipleFileHub;

            // Start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
                test_connection.server.send("test");
            });
        }
        return true;
    });
```

SERVER CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace Portal.Web.Hubs
{
    [HubName("multipleFileHub")]
    public class multipleFileHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            // Call the addMessage method on all clients
            Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

GLOBAL.ASAX ROUTING

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
        routes.Ignore("{*allpng}", new { allpng = @".*\.png(/.*)?" });
        routes.Ignore("{*allgif}", new { allgif = @".*\.gif(/.*)?" });
        routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });

        routes.MapRoute(
        "Error", // Route name
        "Error/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new {controller = "Error", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Landing", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

ALL JAVASCRIPT REFERENCES ON THE PAGE

```
<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/Libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/Libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/Libs/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/Libs/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/Libs/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/Libs/modernizr.custom.blobconstructor.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/SidebarMenu.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/BC_Common.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/scene.layoutservice.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/scene.dataservice.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script src="/ConnectPortal/Scripts/scene.startup.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have jQuery included twice on the page. If you're using MVC4 then you probably have jQuery on the Layout page and are including it again in your SignalR page.

Comment: I pulled up the page using Chrome Dev Tools and found only one version of jquery-2.0.2.min.js.  I've included all the javascript libraries referenced up above.

Comment: That's the only reason I've ever seen that error. You can try removing the layout page and seeing if you can get it to work with the minimal scripts required for that specific page with signalr.

Comment: If you open up the Console in whatever browser you're using, do you see any script/parse errors? Any 404's or anything in Network panel?

Comment: I get this error in the console:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'multipleFileHub' of undefined"

Comment: Here's the full error:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'multipleFileHub' of undefined Index:508
(anonymous function) Index:508
x.event.dispatch jquery-2.0.2.js:4692
y.handle jquery-2.0.2.js:4376"

Comment: Just seems like your jquery.signalR script isn't actually loading. What happens if you use the non-.min version of jquery.signalR and put a breakpoint on line 682 (which should look like this $.connection = $.signalR = signalR)? does it get hit?

Comment: Now we're talkin'!  I put a break point on that line and it gets hit twice before I even get to the click event (which contains the $.connection code).  It doesn't get hit, however, when I call $.connection in the click event.

Comment: Yeah, that's just the initialization logic. I just wanted to see if it was getting registered properly with jQuery. If that's getting hit during page initialization (e.g. the script loading) then $.connection should be available to you in your click event. It's still not working even with the non-min version? The only thing I can even think of at this point is that the $ variable in your onclick is somehow not the same version of jQuery that is present when SignalR is initializing which kind of aligns with what @dfowler was saying with jQuery being re-included. :\

Comment: So if it's getting hit twice during initialization, could it be that the signalr jquery is being loaded twice?

Comment: Yes, it must be, 'cause that's inline script execution. If you saw it hit that BP twice, it had to be included twice.

Comment: Does it matter that my Global.asax inherits from "StsMvcHttpApplication" rather than the standard "System.Web.HttpApplication"?   And in my case, I have to put the "RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();" in my "RegisterRoutes" method rather than "Application_Start" since Application_Start doesn't fire fast enough... it starts hunting for controllers if I put it in that method.

Comment: I think you need to look at it purely from what is rendered to the HTML page at this point. Doesn't matter what's generating the content on the server, *something* seems to double including jQuery and/or jQuery.signalR. Break out the dev tools for your browser and monitor network requests and see what's being loaded when and by what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the cause of this issue was because the jquery library was being loaded on the page a second time.  There was another javascript library being used in the layout that was inserting the non-minified jquery library on the page after the first minified one.  It was hard to find this since the code to insert the other jquery library was not displayed on the layout page.  Anyway, just thought I'd let all who read this know that the issue is DEFINITELY related to the jquery library being added after the signalR library.

David Fowler, from the above comments, was spot on!  Thanks!